# Put CSS on TOP, how?

Tags: css, headers

I have this mission, that regards setting my existing CSS on HEAD.
I've tried to make a search on if there was any kind of plugin or code to automatically set the CSS code directly in Head.
The main purpose is to follow YSlow recomendations such as "Put CSS on Top"

How can i do that? Is there a code for it? a plugin?

Does someone believes that can help me with this?

My domain is http://findout-macau.com

Comment: Are you referring to [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)?

Comment: I haven't tried nothing yet.
My goal is to follow YSlow recomendations.
One of those recomendation were to "put CSS on top"
That being said, i have to add the information that i'm a nobbie... regarding codes.

Comment: I believe it means put the links to CSS files, before any JS (js is blocking) in head. This would be done by editing the header.php of whatever theme you are using.

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help. Is there any other tip you can give me in order for me to understand a bit more what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be interesting to see if you get the same YSlow message when checking your site without any plugins.  Its a little difficult to be sure because of the minification of HTML/CSS on your site, but it seems some of the plugins are not inserting stylesheets in to the `<head>` part of your document, and placing them when they appear instead.

From my understanding of YSlow's documentation http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_top, it helps to ensure progressive loading - or in other words, the visual loading of the site for the end user is enhanced.

If a fresh install of your theme (perhaps on a test site) results in the same YSlow message, then feel free to ignore the above. If not, perhaps activate each plugin and run the test to see which ones are adding them in erroneously - then maybe drop the plugin authors an email.